# how to select the rows between two different two time spans in pgadmin4

Tags: select, timespan, pgadmin-4

I have a table in pgadmin4. one of the columns is date-time . I want to extract all columns when date time is greater than 0 and smaller than 6 and also when date-time is between 18 and 23.

I tried the following query but the result was an empty table.

```sql
select 
*
from tl
where date_part('hour',tl.tstamp) >=0 and date_part('hour',tl.tstamp) <6
and date_part('hour',tl.tstamp) >=18 and date_part('hour',tl.tstamp) <=23;
```

each of these time spans work separately well but when I try to execute them together I have the mentioned problem.

I would appreciate it if somebody could tell me what is the problem and how can I fix it.

Comment: *"I have a table in pgadmin4"* That is a Administration tool for PostgreSQL; you've tagged SQL Server here. What are you *really* using? The above is also *not* valid T-SQL; the function is `DATEPART` in T-SQL, and the first parameter isn't a `varchar`.

Comment: I am using pgadmin4. I edited the title and tags

Comment: All of your conditions are joined together with AND. Do you think t1.tstamp can satisfy all four conditions at the same time? It cannot. What you want to do is evaluate if t1.tstamp is within either period - you need to join those conditions with OR. E.g., where x >= 1 and x < 2 OR x >= 3 and x < 4. Notice the lack of parentheses - you will need to add them yourself which I leave as a learning experience.

Comment: I already tried "OR" between them but the result is a bit weird . the result date_time is not in order. I want to have a clean table that starts with 0 to 6 and then 18 to 23 .. but I got something else

Comment: @SMor yess .. thank you very much the problem was lack of parentheses.